# Syntax to set an array-of-structs element via initializer?

Tags: c, arrays, gcc, struct, c99

I have the following C code:

```
typedef struct {
    int x,y;
} Point2D;

Point2D data[5];
```

Later in my code (i.e. not during initialization of `data`), I want to set individual elements of data from x/y values. The two-statement-code is simple:

```
Point2D pt = {.x = a, .y = b};
data[3] = pt;
```

But is there a way in C to do this in a single statement? Neither of the following ideas seems to be valid C99 code (for GCC 4.8.2):

```
data[3] = {.x = a, .y = b};
data[3] = Point2D{.x = a, .y = b};
data[3] = Point2D(a,b); //C++-like syntax
```

Comment: Why exactly do you need to do this in a single statement? Do you have any rationale why? You can do this with a compound literal but the code won't be faster and it will (arguably) only get harder to read.

Comment: @Lundin: because IMHO the unnecessary temporary variable clutters the code and makes it less legible.

Comment: Dividing long rows into several statements is usually considered to make the code _more_ legible. Writing long code lines which do multiple things at once are generally considered hard to read. Of course, this is all quite subjective. Personally I consider compound literals to be far less readable than what you originally had.

Comment: Yeah, it's quite subjective. In my case even the compound literal is not that long (still far less than 80 chars), and IMHO the compound literal has more the succinct human-readable semantics "set an array element to a new value", while my initial code had the semantics "construct a new temporary struct, and then set an array element to its value". In the latter case, somebody new to the code would have remember the temporary variable and make sure that its value is not also used somewhere else in order to fully comprehend the code. That's not necessary for the compound literal.

Comment: You are making a hard copy of the temporary variable, so whatever happens to it afterwards doesn't matter. And if there is a risk of accidentally re-using a variable, then that suggests that either the code block is too long or that the variable has too broad a scope. Also, if you don't think you are creating a temporary struct when using a compound literal, you are only fooling yourself. The machine code will be identical to your original code with a named struct. Compound literals have the same scope and storage duration as any other local variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a compound literal:

```
data[3] = ( Point2D ){.x = a, .y = b};
```